# .NET Core - The type or namespace name ‘SystemException’ could not be found

Tags: .net-core

I am getting the following compilation error in a .NET Core 1.0 class library:

> “The type or namespace name ‘SystemException’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)”, code: CS0246.

### project.json

```
 {
  "name": "Dna.Net.Core",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Autofac": "4.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
    "System.Runtime": "4.1.0",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters": "4.0.0-rc3-24212-01",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.1.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

### ISystemExceptionMessageBuilder.cs

```
using Dna.Net.Core.Common;
using System;

namespace Dna.Net.Core.Exceptions
{
    public partial interface ISystemExceptionMessageBuilder
    {
        CustomMessage Parse(SystemException ex);
    }
}
```

The [Framework Guideline](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/935018d4c6089871c82d66c43482b24cafd3b58a/Documentation/coding-guidelines/framework-design-guidelines-digest.md) states “DO NOT throw Exception or SystemException”.

A search within the coreFX project shows comments in [classes that have refactored away from System.SystemException](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SystemException).

Can / will / should I be able to catch System.SystemException in .NET Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.SystemException` is not part of .NET Core (at least not `netcoreapp1.0` or `netstandard1.6`). However it [seems](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.SystemException) scheduled for `netcoreapp1.1` or `netstandard1.7`.

The referenced source file of the other answer was probably not compiled into the `System.Runtime` (or its companion `System.Private.CoreLib`.

Answering your question: As of today you should not be able to catch `System.SystemException`. For final handling you should catch `System.Exception` and if you are able to handle the exception, it cannot be a `System.SystemException` in .NET Core.

Comment: thanks for the link to a very helpful resource: [.NET API Catalog](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.SystemException).

Comment: currently the best resource unknown by most. Went live like 2-3 weeks ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

System.SystemException exists in coreCLR - https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/SystemException.cs

So it is available in the mscorlib. So it can be used. But it is not recommended. As you will not get any specific information about the exception when you throw a system exception instead throw a relevant exception. System exception should be limited to system error (platform specific).